# Capture Label text from DataGrid in MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have implemented a `Label` in DataGrid using MVVM. My requirement is when user clicks on the `Label` the events need to be raised which is working fine. But now I would like to capture the label text, but I am unable to acheive this:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="DgPreviousEntries" HeadersVisibility="None"
             ItemsSource="{Binding WeeklyWiseEntries}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedweekEntry}">            
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True" Width="600">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.WeekCommand}">
                                                </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                            </i:EventTrigger>                                            
                                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <Label.Content>
                                            <TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="Mon &#x0a; {0}">
                                                    <Binding Path="Monday" Source="Monday" />                                        
                                                 </MultiBinding>
                                            </TextBlock.Text>
                                            </TextBlock>                                            
                                        </Label.Content> 
                                    </Label>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        <DataTemplate>                  
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>   
                <DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try passing the Label Text  as Command Paramter?

`CommandParameter={Binding Path=Content, ElementName=LabelName}`

E.g:

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Name="DayLabel">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction 
        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.WeekCommand}"
        CommandParameter={Binding Path=Content, ElementName=DayLabel}>
        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
    </i:EventTrigger>                                            
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<Label.Content>
    <TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="Mon &#x0a; {0}">
            <Binding Path="Monday" Source="Monday" />                                        
         </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>                                            
</Label.Content> 
</Label>
```

Comment: Hi, but how do i capture the DayLabel (Label) text in my ViewModel ? because i already implemented the content of label.

Comment: Hi i am receiving Null value in ViewModel when i implemented my RelayCommand as  WeekCommand = new RelayCommand(WeekData, null);

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the only change in the answer is {Binding Path=Text, ElementName=DayLabel} should be {Binding Path=Content, ElementName=DayLabel}

Comment: I gave, DayLabel as an example, ideally you can bind the command paramter to any of the property in the viewmodel. Whichever suits you please do.